# Simple GetItem with ctx.identity.username returns null

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, aws-amplify, vtl

I'm using `AppSync` with `IAM auth` with a `DynamoDB resolver` and `Cognito`. I'm trying to do the following.

```js
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "userId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.identity.username)
    }
}
```

`$ctx.identity.username` is supposed to contain `userId` generated by `Cognito` and I'm trying to use it to fetch current user data.

Client side, I'm using `AWS Amplify` that tells me I'm currently logged:

```js
this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.subscribe(authState => {
  if (authState.state === 'signedIn') {
    this.getUserLogged().toPromise();
    this._isAuthenticated.next(true);
  }
});
```

`getUserLogged` is the `Apollo query` that is supposed to returns user data.

What I've tried:

- If I leave it like this, `getUserLogged` returns null.
- If I replace in the resolver `$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.identity.username)` with a known `userId` like this `$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("b1ad0902-2b70-4abd-9acf-e85b62d06fa8")`: It works! I get this user data.
- I tried to use the test tool in the resolver page but it only gives fake data so I can't rely on this.

**Did I make a mistake? To me everything looks good but I guess I'm missing something?**

Can I clearly see what `$ctx.identity` contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `$ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId` to identify Cognito IAM users:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-identity

You could see the contents of `$ctx.identity` by creating a Lambda resolver and logging the event or by creating a local resolver and returning the input that the mapping template receives:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-local-resolvers.html

My `cognitoIdentityId` looks like this: `eu-west-1:27ca1e79-a238-4085-9099-9f1570cd5fcf`

Comment: Alright. I can try that but are you sure that `$ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId` is not linked to devices? What if this user comes with another device. Will he have the same value in `$ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId`? What if he wants to loggin with `Twitter` latter. Will there still be the same value in `$ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId`? Thank you for your help @mikuz.

Comment: The context reference recommends using `cognitoIdentityId` for identifying users from Cognito Federeated Identities. I see no evidence of it binding to a device but you can test that hypothesis. Connecting Twitter login to User Pools login? I don't think that's something that Federated Identities supports. Certainly you can develop a system to connect the logins from the two providers (you'll probably need to use Lambda resolvers for that).

Comment: It seems that `cognitoIdentityId ` is not available in `Cognito` triggers. I'm currently using a trigger to store an uniq userId generated by Cognito. An Id I can use in my resolvers. I'm lost.

Comment: This answer should help you with using the Cognito UserPools user and Federated Identities IAM user together https://stackoverflow.com/a/50109477/1207523

Comment: So I have to use a `Lambda` function to get the author from every single query made?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In that answer I describe a system where all user data (UserPool and Federated Identities) are stored in a DynamoDB item during login. In GraphQL you can retrieve that data in any query by having a DynamoDB resolver on `author` field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174590/discussion-between-tom-and-mikuz).